# Stop Execution Php

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code , iam trying to use javascript to stop executing but its not working with javascript , any suggestions ? Am just trying to stop executing if the return was false from the javascript

```
if(mysql_num_rows($runzz)==0){

        echo "<p align='center'><font size='5'>This Item $code1 - $code2 - ".$rw2['description']. "</br></br> Doesn't Exist In The <u><b>".$rowto['name']."</b></u></br></br> Wanna Add IT ?</font></p>";

    ?>
<script>
function check(){
var r = confirm("Press a button!");
if (r == true) {
   return true;
} else {
   return false;
}
}
check();
</script>
<?php   
    }
$insert="INSERT INTO transfercopy(warehouseidfrom,warehouseidto,qty,itemid,uid)VALUES('$from','$to','$qty','$codeid','$uid')";
$run=mysql_query($insert,$con);
if(!$run)die("error".mysql_error());
```

Comment: javascript runs in browser, PHP runs on server.... so what should stop eexecuting?

Comment: any other way i can use to stop executing the php instead of a javascript confirm box ?

Comment: you will have to store the response in a variable and then call another php file using ajax call based on the response from check function

Comment: Ever considered using a link or a form button to trigger a second php script later?

Comment: Pavan Jiwnani i didnt get the method , how it can be done in a simpler words ,

Comment: PHP executes then serves the JS/HTML/CSS/etc. PHP isn't there once the JS is displayed. You can load the page then have JS send an ajax to a PHP script. 1. The browser sends a request to the server (request). 2. Server processes requests generates content and returns it (server/PHP). 3. Browser renders content returned (js/html/css/anything client side).

Answer (score 1):

I am adding sample code to give you an idea, how you could use AJAX Call with it.

```
<?php
if(mysql_num_rows($runzz)==0){

echo "<p align='center'><font size='5'>This Item $code1 - $code2 - ".$rw2['description']. "</br></br> Doesn't Exist In The <u><b>".$rowto['name']."</b></u></br></br> Wanna Add IT ?</font></p>";

?>
<script>
    function check(){
        var r = confirm("Press a button!");

        if(r) {
            // Add additional parameter
            // You could use POST method too. Use whatever make sense to you. 
            var urlLink = 'http://www.example.com/warehouse/record.php?from=<?php echo $from?>&to=<?php echo $to?>';

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: urlLink,
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data == 'success') {
                        return 'You have successfully added new record!';   
                    }
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        } else {
         return false;   
        }
    }
   check();
</script>
<?php } ?>

<?php
// -- New File: record.php File 
//    
// You might wanna add the check, that it's the legit request and all the PHP Validation

$form = $_GET['from'];
$to = $_GET['to'];
$qty = $_GET['qty'];
$codeid = $_GET['codeid'];
$uid = $_GET['uid'];

$insert="INSERT INTO transfercopy(warehouseidfrom,warehouseidto,qty,itemid,uid)VALUES('$from','$to','$qty','$codeid','$uid')";
$run=mysql_query($insert,$con);
if(!$run) die("error".mysql_error());
else return 'success';

?>
```